# how can i add the same logo in multiple photos

Tags: lightroom, watermark

I want to add the club logo on the photos but as they are quite a lot I was wondering if there is a faster way instead of doing it manually.

The programs I currently have are Lightroom and Photoshop Elements 9.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Create a watermark using the logo and use either Photoshop or Lightroom to apply it to a batch of images.

If the photos are varying dimensions see [here](http://www.ps-bridge-scripts.talktalk.net/) for how to apply it uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my watermarking program [SquiggleMark](http://www.osletek.com/squigglemark). (Disclaimer: I am the author of SquiggleMark)

It is free to use.

You can position your watermark, resize it, set its transparency, and watermark a bunch of files all at once. Works on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu.